# zsh TRAPZERR - get command run

Tags: bash, zsh

I'm trying to trigger something in the `TRAPZERR` function with zsh. I need the command that has not been found but can't find a way to get it. This is the first time I write zsh so sorry if it's obvious

```
TRAPZERR() {
    # catch the "not found" commands
    if [ $? -eq 127 ]; then
        # how to get the command that has been run?
    fi
}
```

Comment: does zsh support the `$_` variable. In other shells that is the most recent command executed, but I'm not sure if that applies to a script, or just the cmd-line. Also. better to do something like `misspelledCmdName; myRc=$?; TRAPZERR $_ $myRc` and use another local var rather than `$?` in the function. ANY command executed resets the value of `$?`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter $_ only gives me ]. I'm not following with the myRc=$? thing, how am I supposed to use this?

Comment: can't read that. please use back-ticks to surround items like my "sample code" above, like `$_`. I'm saying to capture the return code of any important cmd with a special variable, like `goodCmd; cmd1rc=$?; misspelledCmd; cmd2rc=$?`. Taking off for the day. May be get look at S.O. when I get home later. Good luck.

Comment: Why not use the [command_not_found_handler](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html)?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Perfect! I didn't know that function. Can you write this as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger an action upon a *not found command*, you can use the special [command_not_found_handler](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Command-Execution.html) hook function. That's the equivalent of `bash`'s `command_not_found_handle` but with the typo fixed.

Note that that function is executed in subshell context, so any variable you set there for instance won't be seen by the parent shell.

```
$ command_not_found_handler() print -ru2 -- $1 was not found
$ asdasd
asdasd was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

As @shellter points out, in `TRAPZERR`, the command name will be found in `$_`, but you need to store it before running any command otherwise, it will be overridden:

```
TRAPZERR() {
  local cmd=$_ code=$?
  if (( code == 127 )); then
    print -ru2 -- "Most probably, $cmd was not found"
  fi
}
```

But beware:

```
$ asdasda
zsh: command not found: asdasda
Most probably, asdasda was not found
$ (asdad)
zsh: command not found: asdad
Most probably, asdad was not found
Most probably,  was not found
```

Above, 127 is the exit status of `asdad` but also of the subshell, hence the two messages.

Also note that there are contexts where `TRAPZERR` is not called (the same ones where `set -e` doesn't cause the shell to exit):

```
$ asasdasd || :
zsh: command not found: asasdasd
```

So, two reasons why you may want to use [command_not_found_handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20744884/1627296) instead.

Comment: For me `local cmd=$_` just puts "local" in `cmd`.